# Registering jaxws:client as a Spring bean in Spring Boot Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cxf

I saw a java project where a webservice client was generated using WSDL2Java command. The project also contained a spring.xml with the below config :

```
<jaxws:client
    id = "com.xyz.connector"
    serviceClass = "com.xyz.XYZServicePort"
    address = "<endpoint url from config>"
    bus="XYZServiceBus">
</jaxws:client>
<bean id = "XYZPasswordCallback" class = "com.xyz.ClientPasswordCallback">
    <property name = "password" value = "<password from config>"/>
</bean>
<bean id = "logInbound" class = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id = "logOutbound" class = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
<cxf:bus bus="XYZServiceBus">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean = "logInbound"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean = "logOutbound"/>
        <bean class = "org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key = "action" value = "UsernameToken"/>
                    <entry key = "addUTElements" value = "Unique ID Created"/>
                    <entry key = "user" value = "<user id from config>"/>
                    <entry key = "passwordType" value = "PasswordText"/>
                    <entry key = "passwordCallbackRef" value-ref = "XYZServiceBus"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean = "logOutbound"/>
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean = "logInbound"/>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

There is a Java class file where the above listed spring.xml has been loaded using the below annotation.

```
@ImportResource({ /*"classpath:config.xml",*/ "classpath*:META-INF/application-context.xml", "classpath*:META-INF/spring.xml" })
```

XYZServicePort is autowired using annotation in the class. XYZServicePort is then used for calling the operations exposed by the service.

The xml snippet pertinent to spring.xml is the only config file that is added to the webservice client project which was generated using wsdl2java command. I don't see any configuration in spring.xml or annotation in the code which defines XYZServicePort as a bean. Does the xml snippet present in spring.xml somehow converts the XYZServicePort to a spring bean?

Comment: Please help in letting me know if I need explore further or provide more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`<jaxws:client>` that can be used on the client side.** You'll give it a bean name, the service interface, and the service URL, and **CXF will create a bean with the specified name, implementing the service interface, and invoking the remote SOAP service** that need to injected in the Spring where ever the call is required for this client.

For futher details please refer the following URL's:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Hope this will helps !

Comment: You are Welcome Vicky

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problem you have - is something about @wsdl2java@ client code is not working?

Addressing your question:

```
Does the xml snippet present in spring.xml somehow converts the XYZServicePort to a spring bean?
```

CXF has quite nice docs about how it integrates with Spring:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/server-service-and-client-factorybeans.html
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Basically, CXF during Spring initalization registers it's own "factory beans" - classes which knows how to "produce" beans into Spring App Context.

So probably what you are looking for is **JaxWsClientFactoryBean**

https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/JaxWsClientFactoryBean.html

**-- EDIT: explain how those factory beans are invoked --**
1. You have CXF client project which contains CXF jars on classpath
2. During classloading JVM loads all jars and SPIs in them
3. CXF registers itself as a provider for "javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider" (inside **cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.1.jar** there is a file /META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider which points to **org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl**)
4. When your client code instantiates your JAXWS service which **extends javax.xml.ws.Service**, then the protected constructor of javax.xml.ws.Service contacts registered SPI providers (the CXF one) and the magic begins :)

You should put breakpoint on code e.g.

```
TestService ss = new TestService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
```

and debug it for yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!!The code that is listed is working fine. The client gets imported and it works as expected. However I am unable to understand how XYZServicePort is converted to a bean as I don't see any explicit config around it. The code / config listed is all that is present in the code and I don't see JaxWsClientFactoryBean being used. Does the config listed above convert XYZServicePort  into a bean? I went over the docs that you shared but still could quite get how the code / config listed in my post is causing XYZServicePort to be registered as a Spring bean.

Comment: @PunterVicky I've added explanation to my answer about how CXF is working.